# Validation errors make no sense

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

Can someone explain to me the errors I am receiving while trying to validate my site, they are too long to mention here specifically but most are in reference to meta tags, if you go to w3c validation and validate, http://sunnahspace.com you will see the errors. I have a lot of difficulty understanding these errors when validating, a fix for these would be good but what I am looking for is someone who can explain WHY these errors are occurring so I don't have to ask for help every time I validate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: YOu'd think you'd have better things to do on Eid than to work :-P

Comment: the w3c validator says exactly why each error is occurring. read the explanation underneath each error

Comment: eid was yesterday for me Ali, but even then I was working a bit, I have a radio interview with CII on Monday to promote the site and would like it to be usable to some degree by then insha'Allah :P

Comment: marissa, I see that, however it lacks the ability to put it into laymans terms for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the SRC and META tag erros are probably because you are using XHTML and tags and attributes should be lowercase characters. The errors in the url (bid) are because you have to use a `&amp;` character instead of `&`.

Comment: brilliant, and your description also helped me understand why this was happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Error Line 5, Column 12: there is no attribute "name"
Line 5, Column 28: there is no attribute "content"
Line 5, Column 46: element "META" undefined

- You used capital letters for META. This isn't valid code when using an XHTML doctype. You must use lowercase letters.

Error Line 21, Column 7: end tag for "META" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
Line 5, Column 1: start tag was here
Line 21, Column 7: end tag for "head" which is not finished

- You have to close each tag in XHTML with "/>" instead of ">" otherwise you will have invalid xhtml code.

Line 75, Column 18: there is no attribute "LANGUAGE"
Line 75, Column 38: there is no attribute "SRC"
Line 75, Column 128: element "SCRIPT" undefined

- This is not valid xhtml code. It should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="…"></script>`

Line 75, Column 93: cannot generate system identifier for general entity "bid"

- The & needs to be coded as `&amp;` so the browser can read the url correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using an XHTML DocType but have uppercase tag names and attribute keys. All tag names and attribute keys should be lowercase. All attribute values should be enclosed in quotation marks.

```
<META name="y_key" content="dcd27d28fcb65dc2" />
```

should be

```
<meta name="y_key" content="dcd27d28fcb65dc2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Majority of your problems seem to be:

- make tag names (`script`, `meta`) and attributes (`src`,`language`, `content` etc) lowercase.
- The META tag is not closed.... I know... it's odd. remove `/` before it's close.
- Javascript remove `language` or make it `language="javascript"` and close it with `</script>` instead of with a `/>` though I think it shouldn't matter for javascript tags.

Comment: If someone marked me down because I said the meta tag is not closed. Then [read the documentation yourself](http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html) or [look at this link](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/empty.html) which explains it... sorta.

Comment: Good answer Ali, eid mubarak bro.

Comment: Eid is traditionally 3 days, of which at least 2 days people take seriously. I'm in Pakistan and it was today for me. But I realize that taking time off on Eid is a luxury only afforded in Muslim countries. There is a proposal for a Muslim community questions site like StackOverflow, do sign up if you havent.[area51.StackExchange.com Muslim site Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam)

Comment: I did already :) yeah, I generally focus on the eid prayer, the 3 days of eid for me just mean I can't fast until they are over :P my mother is in pakistan, shes a convert too. If you are interested, SunnahSpace is always looking for people to jump on board, right now it's me with my basic coding skills and a sister in Morocco who does most of the design.

Comment: Contact me through the email address on my website and perhaps we can set something up.